# How can Rpi python GPIO 5V relay control a 12V solenoid door Lock?

Tags: raspbian, python

I am trying to connect a 12V AC/DC lock to my Raspberry PI 3B+ so I can control it using python3 on the raspberry pi. Does anyone know anything I can do.

Here are my parts:

Electric lock: https://www.jaycar.com.au/12v-ac-dc-door-strike-release/p/LA5078
Relay board: https://www.jaycar.com.au/arduino-compatible-5v-relay-board/p/XC4419
Raspberry Pi 3B+

Comment: What have you actually done?  You probably won't be able to reliably control a 5V relay module from the 3V3 Pi.

Comment: Ah, let me see.  Your door lock is an "Electric Strike".  ***You cannot control it using any relay!*** (1) Electric strike - Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_strike

(2) Electric Strikes - Openers-Closers
https://openers-closers.com/source/ELECTRIC%20STRIKES_2018.pdf

Comment: So It is impossible for me to control that door lock with a raspberry pi? @tlfong01

Comment: Ah, not at all. For us hobbyists, check out this 12V door lock catalog for those using "***solenoids***", not "electric strikes": https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-12v-door-lock.html.

Comment: And because a 12V door lock is just a 12V solenod with a "tail". So what you need to mess around it use a 5V relay to control the solenoid (Example, ***ZYE-1 12V solenoid***). You may find the schematic below helpful: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=230325&p=1412816&hilit=door+lock+tlfong01#p1412820. Cheers.

Comment: And this shows the real thing: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=230325&p=1412816&hilit=door+lock+tlfong01#p1412875. You see that I do not start with using Rpi python GPIO to control the relay. I use a NE555 timer to control the relay. Only I after I make sure how N555 can control the relay, then I replace NE555 by Rpi GPIO. So if you newbie fry things, you only fry a cheapy 555, not the expensive Rpi. And actually using 555 in the prototyping stage is faster that using python. Cheers.

Comment: And this YouTube shows how you can use the cheapy solenoid to fake a lousy door dock: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYSmZUaBNzA&feature=youtu.be.

Comment: And you can search "KY019 relay tlfong01" in rpi.org.forum to find 100+ posts on how to use Rpi python to control different kinds of relays. Or start with this post: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=77158#p1323061 Happy program programming.

Answer (score 2):

Aiden, the Pi is 3.3V, so on first glance the relay board may not work reliably. However the wiring should be straight forward, just do a search on raspberry pi gpio and relays.

Comment: any idea how to connect the relay board so I can control the lock with the raspberry pi? @dave

Answer (score 2):

The 5V rating refers to the **coil**; 12V refers to the solenoid door lock rating.

Here's how to set up the hardware:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftOlfI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Use a transistor as a switch and use 12V across that transistor. This is the safest way. Measure the relay resistance first to choose your transistor.